# How to put the image at the upper left corner of the screen?

Tags: java, image, position, coordinates, drawimage

I have an image and it appears at the bottom left part, I want it to appear at the upper left corner. I already tried different x,y coordinates but still the same, it doesn't change. I know this is not really difficult but I'm just confused. Please help me regarding this matter. huhu... T_T, thanks in advance.

this is my code:

```
public class DonPaking extends Sprite implements ImageObserver
{
private java.awt.Image donImage;
private final Sea sea;
private double x;
private double y;
private final double donHeight = 1.6;
private final double donWidth = 1.8; 
private double speed;
private boolean visible;
private double angle;
private double dx_m;
private double dy_m;

private boolean collision = false;

public DonPaking(Sea sea, String name, double x, double y, double speed)
{
    super(name);
    this.sea = sea;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.speed = convertToMeterPerSecond(speed);
    visible = true;

    URL iU = this.getClass().getResource("don.jpg");
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(iU);
    donImage = icon.getImage();

}

public Image getImage()
{
    return donImage;
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{

    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
    {
        dx_m = -0.3;
    }
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
    {
        dx_m = 0.3;
    }
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    {
        dy_m = 0.3;
    }
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
    {
        dy_m = -0.3;
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
{
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
    {
        dx_m = 0;
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
    {
        dx_m = 0;
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    {
        dy_m = 0;
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
    {
        dy_m = 0;
    }
}

@Override
public void move(long dt)
{
    double dt_s = dt / 1e9;

    final double right_wall = sea.x1_world;
    final double up_wall = sea.y1_world;
    final double down_wall = 0.0;
    final double left_wall = 0.0;

    x += dx_m;
    y += dy_m;


    if (x >= right_wall)
    {
        x = right_wall;
    }
    if (x <= left_wall)
    {
        x = left_wall;
    }

    if (y <= down_wall)
    {
        y = down_wall;
    }

    if (y >= up_wall)
    {
        y = up_wall;
    }

}

@Override
public void render(Graphics2D g2d)
{
    AffineTransform t = g2d.getTransform();

    final double foot_position_y = donHeight;
    final double foot_position_x = donWidth / 2;

    int xx = sea.convertToPixelX(x - foot_position_x); 
    int yy = sea.convertToPixelY(y + foot_position_y); 

    g2d.translate(xx, yy);

    double x_expected_pixels = donHeight * sea.meter;
    double y_expected_pixels = donWidth * sea.meter;

    double w = ((ToolkitImage) donImage).getWidth();
    double h = ((ToolkitImage) donImage).getHeight();

    double x_s = x_expected_pixels / w;
    double y_s = y_expected_pixels / h;

    g2d.scale(x_s, y_s);
    g2d.drawImage(getImage(), 0, 0, this); 

    g2d.setTransform(t);
}

@Override
public void moveAt(double distance_x, double distance_y)
{
    this.x = distance_x;
    this.y = distance_y;
}

public void setAngle(double angle)
{
    this.angle = angle;
}


@Override
public RectangleX getBounds()
{
    return new RectangleX(x, y, donWidth, donHeight);
}

@Override
public double getWidth()
{
    return WIDTH;
}

@Override
public double getHeight()
{
    return HEIGHT;
}

@Override
public boolean imageUpdate(Image img, int infoflags, int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    return true;
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

The coordinates for the top/left are (0, 0). So get rid of the translate(..) method and the image will be painted at the coordinates you specified.

Comment: the problem is if I remove the translate(), the image won't move.

Comment: Your question is about displaying the image at the top/left. So the initial values of your translate variables should be (0, 0). Then when you move the image the translate varaibles should change. If the image doesn'tmove the way your want it to move then your translate calculation is wrong. So debug your tranlate logic.